# Error: [ERR] adb.exe: device 'emulator-5554' not found while trying to use my emulator

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling, android-emulator

I can't use my emulator. This error keeps popping up in my output panel saying:

> [ERR] Error 1 retrieving device properties for sdk gphone64 x86 64:
> [ERR] adb.exe: device 'emulator-5554' not found

See also these images:

[image]

[image]

Comment: first of all install google chrome in your machine and also vscode
then check is SDK path set correctly in android studio or have you installed android SDK